# Difference between lifting and higher order functions

Tags: functional-programming, lifting

I usually hear the term lifting, when people are talking about `map`, `fold`, or `bind`, but isn't basically every higher order function some kind of lifting?

Why can't `filter` be a lift from `a -> Bool` to `[a] -> [a]`, heck even the `bool` function (which models an if statement) can be considered a lift from `a -> a` to `Bool -> a`. And if they are not, then why is `ap` from the Applicative type class considered a lift?

If the important thing is going from `... a ...` to `... f a ...`, then `ap` wouldn't fit the case either: `f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has answered this already.

A lifting function's role is to lift a function into a context (typically a Functor or Monad).  So lifting a function of type `a -> b` into a `List` context would result in a function of type `List[a] -> List[b]`.  If you think about it this is exactly what `map` (or `fmap` in Haskell) does.  In fact, it is part of the definition of a Functor.

However, a Functor can only lift functions of one argument.  We also want to be able to deal with functions of other arities as well.  For example if we have a function of type `a -> b -> c` we cannot use `map`.  This is where a more general lifting operation comes into the picture.  In Haskell we have a `lift2` for this case:

```
lift2:: (a -> b -> c) -> (M[a] -> M[b] -> M[c])
```

where `M[a]` is some particular Monad (like `List`) parameterized with a given type `a`.

There are additional variants of `lift` defined as well for other arities.

This is also why `filter` is not a lifting function as it doesn't fit the type signature required; you are not lifting a function of type `a -> bool` to `M[a] -> M[bool]`.  It is, however, a higher-ordered function.

If you want to read more about lifting the Haskell Wiki has a [good article on it](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting)